# Round decimal value based on specific logic

Tags: c#

I may have decimal value. I want to *round* such *decimal value* only if it's greater than *300* and it's *integer part* ends by either *5* or *9* and *round* it either down or up based on logic shown below in example area. If there is any `decimal place` value the result should make it `0`.  Is there any way to achieve that?

**Logic for values where integer part ends with 9:**

```
Value ends on   Round to      Some Example inputs:   Final result (value rounded down)
9               99            609                    599                         
19              99            319,45                 299
                              1019                   999


Value ends on   Round to      Example inputs:        Final result (value rounded up)
29              49            429                    449                         
39              49            439,88                 449


Value ends on   Round to      Example inputs:        Final result (value rounded up)
59              99            1059,12                1099                         
69              99            1069                   1099
79              99            1079                   1099
89              99            1089                   1099
```

**Logic for values where integer part ends with 5:**

*it's very similar logic but we round to 5 instead of 9 nevertheless let's see:*

```
Value ends on   Round to      Some Example inputs:    Final result (value rounded down)
5               95            605                     595                         
15              95            315,45                  295
                              1015                    995


Value ends on   Round to      Example inputs:         Final result (value rounded up)
25              45            425                     445                         
35              45            435,88                  445


Value ends on   Round to      Example inputs:         Final result (value rounded up)
55              95            1055,12                 1095                         
65              95            1065                    1095
75              95            1075                    1095
85              95            1085                    1095
```

**EDIT for further comments discussion:**

```
public decimal ProcessFormatting(decimal value)
{
    //we only intrested to round value > 300 otherwise return
    if (value < 300 ) return value;

    int @base;
    @base = (int)Math.Round(Math.Truncate(value / 10) * 10);

    var temp = value - @base;
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this C# but C# doesn't have `DECIMAL(18, 2)`, that's an SQL thing. C# only has `decimal`, which is not quite the same thing, as C#'s decimals are true decimal floating-point types (no fixed precision like SQL). So are you asking a C# or an SQL question?

Comment: It's basic math. Multiply by 10, round that, convert to integer and use modulo 10 to check last digit.

Comment: @paddy can u post as an answer showing that so then i can also mark as an asnwer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert u right i made mistake but i'm still asking with regards to C#. Corrected the post.

Comment: I don't know C#, I'm just telling you how to do it in basically any language.

Comment: @paddy ok will check that

Comment: @paddy multiplying by 10 does not help. The only digits we are interested in are the ones and the tens. so dividing by 10 (integer division) is much more helpful

Comment: I misread, and thought they were trying to examine the digit in the first decimal place. Anyway, the technique is adaptable to whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments give a good idea of how to do it. The basic idea is:

1. Check if the value is bigger than 300 (else return it unchanged)
2. Check if the integer part of the value ends in 5 or 9 (else return it unchanged).
3. Take the integer part of the value and add some value to it, depending on the tens digit.

There is probably a neater way to actually calculate this, or using a lookup dictionary/array (especially for the last part). But this seems to work quite well:

```cs
public static decimal Round(decimal value)
{
    if (value < 300)
    {
        return value;
    }

    if (((long)value % 10) is not 5 and not 9)
    {
        return value;
    }

    return (long)value + (((long)value / 10) % 10) switch
    {
        0 => -10,
        1 => -20,
        2 or 7 => 20,
        3 or 8 => 10,
        5 => 40,
        6 => 30,
        _ => 0,
    };
}
```

Comment: I made some tests and seems like it works ! U sure there couldn't be any issue accordingly to the given requirment? Thank you.

Comment: I think it should work, but I have not tested it very extensively. If you really want to be sure you will have to test it for yourself. For example what is the requirement for values like `345.1`. This method returns `345`, but your requirement may be `345.1`

Comment: As stated in main post, decimal part is not taken into consideration at all as at the end it has to be 0. We only should look at integer part so it should be fine i guess.